Can I use electromagnet to hold a cabinet door shut while driving (in my campervan)?
I have a bathroom/kitchen cabinet in my camper van that I keep forgetting to close correctly before driving away. Then in the first corner it'll swing open.
I was wondering if I could use an electric magnet that engages when I turn my ignition, to hold the door shut exactly while I'm driving.
(To see how the cabinet is constructed, have a look at the thumbnail of the video.)
Think of like a magnetic door lock like this one in the picture, but in very tiny.

I found those tiny electric magnets on amazon (here) (uxcell 20mm x 15mm DC12V 0.25A 3W 25N Sucking Disc Solenoid Lift Holding Electromagnet)
But then in the specs it says something about a 50% Duty Cycle and max engaged time of 7min:

Voltage: DC12V ;Peak Force :25N; Holding Force :18.75N; Duty-cycle (ED%) : 50%; Electric time:Less than 7 minu;Package Content: 1 x Sucked Type Electromagnet

That wouldn't work then, right?
How could I make this still work? I'm kinda new to electric magnets, to I wonder how cautious I'd need to be. Will it overheat and set my van on fire? Can I trickle it like 100ms on/off, would that keep my door shut? Or could I use a resistor in series? It probably doesn't need to be on 100% power (25N) to hold the door shut. Should I maybe get the 24V one and only supply 12V, would that result in negligible heat?

Why not to use a solenoid just for locking the cabinet (electromagnetic lock), so it will not drain battery and doesn’t overheat also?

It wouldn't drain the battery as it's only powered while the alternator is running. And those couple watts shall be negligible. I'm not sure how a solenoid would help? Would it be 'normally closed' and unlocks  with power? That'd be the wrong way. And 'normally open' wouldn't be different to a magnet, would it?

I feel like we're missing some detail of how the cabinet is constructed. Why not just use a normal magnetic latch?  A solenoid cannot close the door if it's wide open.

I see, didn't realise that I left that open. I've added a picture to the question. Think of an magnetic lock that holds a closed door shut. (It's not supposed to close the door. I've got self-closing hinges. I hoped they'd do the job, but they are not strong enough in corners.)

If you forget to close the door, the electromagnet won't help unless there's only a couple mm distance between the poles. Better to have a Klaxon go off if the door is open when the ignition is switched on. The alarm will quickly train you to shut the door before taking off.

Why not route the ignition wiring through the cabinet door switch, so the van can't be driven with the door open? Or slightly less instrusive, a light on the dash indicating the door's status

I don't really see how in this case an electromagnet could do something that a magnetic latch can't already do.

As a magnetic latch would always be engaged it's as hard as with the current RV latches to open the door (I don't want to put door knobs there). I know its not the most straight forward solution to use a electromagnet to solve the problem. I meant the question above to mean 'how to use an electromagnet' and not 'can someone help me keep my door shut in the easiest way possible'.  I feel we're almost off topic here in the comments.

@Joel I mean when you start ignition the doors become locked by pushing (just once) some latch, bayonet, hook. When you stop ignition push the latch back.

Regarding the electro-magnet it’s hard to predict what force is needed. A electromagnet always heat because of coil resistance. With an added series resistor you can set the current, but of course you will get less force.


I was wondering if I could use an electric magnet that engages when I turn my ignition, to hold the door shut exactly while I'm driving.

Yes, you could use an electromagnet to hold the door shut while the ignition is on. But, there are two caveats.

A magnet will only hold a door closed, not shut it from even slightly open. The attractive force of a magnet varies roughly as the inverse of the air-gap. Even a mm gap could reduce the closing force by one or two orders of magnitude. The magnets need to be in good contact with their corresponding iron plates before they will hold with the force that you expect.

You would need to find a magnet rated for continuous operation. The particular magnets you have linked to are not. You could perhaps, if they are cheap enough, use several in series, as a way of reducing their current and hence heata, or use one rated for a much higher voltageb. If using several, make sure they are suitably mounted so that all the magnets can contact their iron plates cleanly, perhaps three on a rocking triangle, pivoted in the centre.
Basically a bigger magnet doesn't get as hot for the same force. Increase the physical size of the magnet until the power consumption and force meet your specifications.


There are alternatives. Electrically operated locks, which could lock the door without continuous application of power. Indicators, so you could see whether the door was locked from your driving position.
a) Interestingly, if you use N of the same technology magnet in electrical series, mechanical parallel, then if you provide the same voltage, you get the same force independent of N, just with a lower current and temperature rise.
b) If the use voltage is lower than rated, then the current and so holding force will also be lower than rated.

I think I also saw a permanent magnet door "open-holder" in a hospital, and how I think it works is that a strong permanent magnet keeps the door in its position, unless an electro magnet wound around it is turned on in the opposing polarity, thus neutralizing the magnetic field.

@MarcusMüller I thought those are supposed to close the door in the case of power cut. And I remember that I felt heat and noise from those when I inspected some... But there may be several types.

@Neil_UK thanks. This is a very nice answer. As its answering the question I've had and including other advice. Re 'indicators', I don't want to turn off ignition, get up and around the car, open side door, get in, press door cabinet shut (and rest in reverse) -- hence this entire idea. I'll try putting 2 in electrical series, mechanically parallel. It sounds like that should somewhat halve the heat (ie. hopefully somewhat equivalent a 50% duty cycle)

I wonder how the manufactures come up with their ratings. What if I want to build my own magnet with just wire and a metal piece. What is the running current-limiting factor then? Just the ohm's resistance of the wire (I assume that once the magnetic field is built up, the current would stay the same, no?)

@Joel The temperature at which the insulation fails, or maybe 80 C outside case temperature, at which skin damage starts to occur if you touch it. You would have to look at the test to see what was classed as 'too hot'.
